# Call function "ReadAsMultipartAsync" synchronously

Tags: asynchronous, wait, navision

I'm using Navision to call `ReadAsMultipartAsync().Result` in a C# library, but this blocks Navision. If I change the library with await and sync, I can't manage a Task result from Navision, so I would like to call the "ReadAsMultipartAsync" function but in a synchronous way.

If I do something like this: `streamCont.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));` works, but I spent 20 seconds on this case.

There are any way of wait the task of `ReadAsMultipartAsync` without block Navision?. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do it that works. It's funny but this blocks Nav:

```
Task<MultipartMemoryStreamProvider> task = streamContent.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
task.Wait();
```

And these two work fine:

```
Task thread1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => result = streamContent.ReadAsMultipartAsync().Result);
Task.WaitAll(thread1);
```

```
Task tarea1 = new Task(() => result = streamContent.ReadAsMultipartAsync().Result);
tarea1.Start();
tarea1.Wait();
```

I don't know what the difference is between the first option and the others, or if it can give an error in some cases, but for now it seems to work.